# How should IEqualityComparer<T>.Equals and IEqualityComparer<T>.GetHashCode behave on invalid data?

Tags: c#

In my application I have a service method which loads some data. The key identifying the data consists of a key type - which is defined as an enum - and some key values.

```
public enum KeyType
{
    Alpha,
    Bravo,
    Charlie
}

public class KeyData
{
    public KeyType KeyType { get; set; }
    public string AlphaKey { get; set; }
    public string BravoKey { get; set; }
    public int? CharlieKey { get ;set; }
}
```

Which key values are necessary depends on the key type. For instance for key type `Alpha` only `AlphaKey` is needed while for key type `Charlie` both `BravoKey` and `CharlieKey` are needed. When using the key for loading, unknown values for the key type and/or superflous key values are simply ignored and no data is returned.

Now I want to store keys in a collection. No key should appear twice in this collection. When comparing keys two should be only considered equal when they have the same key type and all needed key values for that type are equal too. To achieve this, I want to create a class implementing `IEqualityComparer<KeyData>`.

Since it is mentioned on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) that an override of `GetHashCode` should not throw I picked that up for my class and implemented like so:

```
public class KeyDataComparer : IEqualityComparer<KeyData>
{
    public int GetHashCode(KeyData obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return 0;

        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;

            switch (obj.KeyType)
            {
                case KeyType.Alpha:
                    hash = hash * 486187739 + obj.AlphaKey?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
                    break;
                case KeyType.Bravo:
                    hash = hash * 486187739 + obj.BravoKey?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
                    break;
                case KeyType.Charlie:
                    hash = hash * 486187739 + obj.BravoKey?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
                    hash = hash * 486187739 + obj.CharlieKey?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
                    break;
                default:
                    // use object.GetHashCode() as a fallback
                    hash = obj?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
                    break;
            }

            return hash;
        }
```

The problem now is how to handle invalid key types in `IEqualityComparer<T>.Equals`? I did it so:

```
public bool Equals(KeyData x, KeyData y)
{
    if (x == null)
        return y == null;

    if (x.KeyType != y.KeyType)
        return false;

    switch (x.KeyType)
    {
        case KeyType.Alpha:
            return x.AlphaKey == y.AlphaKey;
        case KeyType.Bravo:
            return x.BravoKey == y.BravoKey;
        case KeyType.Charlie:
            return x.BravoKey == y.BravoKey &&
                x.CharlieKey == y.CharlieKey;
        default:
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

But this doesn't look right because it is an inconsistent behaviour. Is there a meaningful way to have `Equals` and `GetHashCode` behave consistent?

Comment: I'd be fine with `GetHashCode` throwing on data that should never exist. You already have a bug, so fail fast.

Comment: Why is that type mutable? I recommend making keys immutable and validating them in the constructor.

Comment: @CodesInChaos The type is just a "dumb" DTO which is sent over WCF routes and serialized and deserialized at the endpoints. Therefore no parametrized constructors are allowed.

Comment: How *do* you want equals and gethashcode to behave?  Is there some behavior (like always being unequal on invalid data) that is meaningful for your specific use case?

Comment: @RobertHarvey TBH as invalid data shouldn't happen (I know this is wishful thinking) and is ignored anyway I haven't really thought about it. But you have a good point and I certainly should've.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can return `false` or `x.ReferenceEquals(y)` and be consistent with your `GetHashCode` implementation.

Note that you dereference `y` without checking it is null. A safer first check would be

```
if ((x == null) != (y == null))
    return false;
```